# $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} = \mathbb{F}_p.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

What is maximal ideal $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ ? And how it is calculated?
Also why  $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} = \mathbb{F}_p.$?

I know $p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is maximal ideal for $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ but how? I know  $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} $ is local so it has unique maximal ideal .

Comment: More generally, whenever $A$ is a ring and $p$ is a prime ideal of $A$, $pA_p$ is the unique maximal ideal of $A_p$ and $A_p/pA_p \simeq Frac(A/p)$

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990036/how-to-directly-show-that-mathbbz-p-is-a-local-ring-with-the-unique-max).

Comment: @DietrichBurde then why the isomorphisam to F_(p)?

Comment: Because a quotient by a maximal ideal must be a field, with $p$ elements. So it follows.

Comment: Why does it have p elements?@DietrichBurde

Comment: Just by definition!

Comment: How sir? Can you explain it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact $A_{(p)}$ is a local ring, i.e. it has a unique maximal ideal of the form 
$$ m_p=\{ \frac {p}{s} ; p\in (p), s\in A-(p)  \} $$
to see that $m_p$is maximal ideal, every element of $A_{(p)}$ not in $m_p$ is the form $\frac{s'}{s}$ with $s'\in A-(p)$, and so has an inverse $\frac{s}{s'}$ and is hence a unit.

Answer (score 0):

You have the local ring $$\mathbb Z_{(p)} = \{ \frac{a}{b} : a, b \in\mathbb Z, p \nmid b\}$$ with its unique maximal ideal $$p\mathbb Z_{(p)} = \{ \frac{a}{b}  : a, b \in \mathbb Z, p \mid a, p \nmid b\}$$

By definition, $\mathbb F_p$ is the quotient ring $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Consider the composition $\phi$ of ring homomorphisms

$$\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{(p)} \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{(p)}/p\mathbb Z_{(p)}$$

Show that $\phi$ is surjective, and that the kernel is $p\mathbb Z$.  The first isomorphism theorem induces an isomorphism of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z = \mathbb F_p$ with $\mathbb Z_{(p)}/p\mathbb Z_{(p)}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a commutative ring and $P$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then the unique maximal ideal of $A_P$ is
$$
P_P=\left\{\frac{a}{b}:a\in P,b\notin P\right\}=PA_P
$$
That this is an ideal is obvious; if $a/b\notin PA_P$, then $a\notin P$, so $(a/b)^{-1}=b/a$. Thus $A_P$ is local with maximal ideal $P_P$.

The quotient ring $A_P/P_P$ is isomorphic to $A/P$. More precisely, the ring homomorphism
$$
A\to A_P/P_P,\qquad a\mapsto \frac{a}{1}+P_P
$$
is (obviously) surjective and its kernel is $P$; indeed, $a/1\in P_P$ means there exist $r\in P$ and $s\notin P$ with
$$
\frac{a}{1}=\frac{r}{s}
$$
so there is $t\notin P$ with $ast=rt$. Since $rt\in P$ and $st\notin P$, it follows that $a\in P$.